# Assigning a declared variable to a string in array javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have these global variables:

```
var name, car;
```

Then I declare some values:

```
const languageStrings = {
    WELCOME_MESSAGE: 'Welcome #name, you have a #car',
    NAME_USER: "#name",
    CAR_USER: '#car'
};
```

And then I need to assign it to a function.
For example:

```
if (firstTime){
    welcomeMsg = WELCOME_MESSAGE;
}
```

Now, I have two questions:

1) How would I insert a variable inside of a string so it is dynamically updated when the value pair is called?

2) How would I do the same using JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a JSON structure or string "automatically" update when some variable changes. There are other ways to do this type of templating, though. You could create a function to create a welcome message when you need one:

```
function getWelcomeMessage(name, car) {
  return "Welcome "+name+", you have a "+car;
}
```

Then you'd do something like `welcomeMsg = getWelcomeMessage("Joe", "Camry");`

If you don't want to write a function for every template (i.e. if you have lots of them), then you could use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) like this:

```
function applyTemplate(template, params) {
  return template.replace(/#(\w+)/g, (m, name) => params[name]);
}
```

Example usage:

```js
function applyTemplate(template, params) {
  return template.replace(/#(\w+)/g, (m, name) => params[name]);
}

const WELCOME_TEMPLATE = "Welcome #name, you have a #car";

var name = "Joe";
var car  = "Camry";
var welcomeMessage = applyTemplate(WELCOME_TEMPLATE, {name, car});
console.log(welcomeMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make a function that returns the value of the variable.

In your case:

```
welcomeMessage = function(){
   return WELCOME_MESSAGE
}
```

and you would reference the variable with:

```
welcomeMessage()
```

So, you'd be assigning a variable as a function that returns the current value of the other variable. You get the value by calling your variable as a function.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question on how to insert variables inside a string is:

```
WELCOME_MESSAGE: 'Welcome ' + name + ', you have a ' + car,
```

or before defining:

```
function mesg(name, car){
    return "Welcome" + name + ", you have a " + car;
}
mesg(bob, BMW);
```

in this case, the name and car is defined after.

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer I tried that already and it works once I declare the values before. This is different. I'm using the values before declaring them.

Answer (score 0):

String in JavaScript is primitive type, it's passed by value. So once a variable is assigned with a string, it will never change until you explicitly assign another value (or object reference) to it.

However, you can [ask object type for help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), which could make your data **reactively** (or dynamically, if you prefer this word) update under certain conditions.

```
var languageStrings = {
  WELCOME_MESSAGE: '',
  NAME_USER: '',
  CAR_USER: ''
}

Object.defineProperty(languageStrings, 'name', {
  get: function (name) {
    return this.NAME_USER
  },
  set: function (name) {
    this.NAME_USER = name
    this.WELCOME_MESSAGE = `Welcome ${this.name}, you have a ${this.car}.`
  }
})

Object.defineProperty(languageStrings, 'car', {
  get: function (car) {
    return this.CAR_USER
  },
  set: function (car) {
    this.CAR_USER = car
    this.WELCOME_MESSAGE = `Welcome ${this.name}, you have a ${this.car}.`
  }
})
```

Now, whenever you change `languageStrings.name` or `languageStrings.car`, all three strings you want will automatically adopt the new value you just set:

```
languageStrings.name = 'Leo'
languageStrings.car = 'BMW'

for (let key in languageStrings) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${languageStrings[key]}`)
}
// WELCOME_MESSAGE: Welcome Leo, you have a BMW.
// NAME_USER: Leo
// CAR_USER: BMW
```

You don't have to manually call `applyTemplate` all the time, like in @qxz's answer (I'm not saying his wrong, though).

Also, please notice that even `name` and `car` are not enumerable - they will not be accessed with `for in`, `for of`, or `Object.keys`! This is great, your implementation details are concealed, no worries or confusions to other developers who use your code.

In fact, such reactive model is widely used in front-end MV* frameworks nowadays, e.g. [Vue](https://vuejs.org/).

Regarding your second question, I didn't get it honestly. Just `JSON.parse` then it's all ordinary JavaScript, isn't it?